# Function from A to A

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $S = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ how many functions from $S \to S$ and how many of these are $bijective$

Say we also had $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ then the number of functions would be $B^A$ and the number of $bijective$ functions would be 5? But how you count the function from the same set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of arbitrary functions is, as you said, $5^5 = 3125$. For bijective $\Leftrightarrow$ injective OR surjective in this case (why?) you have $5!$ since $f(i)$ may be any value in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ except for those "occupied" by $f(j), j < i$ so the total amount is
$$5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1=5!=120$$

---

More generally:
Given finite sets $A,B$ the number of functions $f: A\to B$ is
$$|B|^{|A|}$$
and the number of bijective functions is
$$\frac{|B|!}{(|B|-|A|)!} = \prod_{k=0}^{|A|-1} (|B|-k)$$

Comment: So even with one set the arbitary number of functions would be $N^n$? and $5!$ would in this example serve as the number of bijective functions? Just want to make sure I got it right.

Comment: @user2008560 Not quite if I understood correctly. Refer to my edit for clarification.

Comment: I think I got it now, the general definition you provided for bijective functions $\frac{|B|!}{(|B|-|A|)!}$ helped me undderstand why there are 120 bijective functions in my original question.

Comment: @user2008560 Happy to help :) If that solved your question, please mark it as answered. // I also expanded the general expression to more accurately reflect the course of argument taken to obtain the expression.